# jQuery click event not firing after a different click event has been used

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidedown, slideup

I am completely lost here, I have no idea as to why this is happening.

I have the following code in a .js file:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    showMessage();
    $( '#message' ).slideDown( 'fast' );

    //Hide Message//
    $( '#m_close' ).click(function( event ) {
        $( '#message' ).slideUp( 'fast' );
    });
    //---//
    $( '#m_button' ).click(function( event ) {
    showMessage();
    $( '#message' ).slideDown( 'fast' );
    });
});
```

Now, the message div is created and slides down perfectly fine when the page first loads. When I press #m_close, the div slides up perfectly. However, if I press #m_button, the message slides down with all the right info, but pressing #m_close does absolutely nothing. I get no errors in the dev console, nothing seems to go wrong, it just refuses to work. I added a slideDown to the #m_close so that it would close then reopen, and it does that, and the #m_close will work infinitely, until #m_button is pressed.

What is going on?

EDIT: my HTML per request:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="includes/style.1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="includes/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="message">

    </div>
    <button id="m_button">Message</button>
    <script src="includes/functions.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Can add your HTML and showMessage()? or a jsfiddle?

Comment: I added to my original post.

Comment: is `m_close` added dynamically to the page

Comment: yes, it is created in the `showMessage` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the message is loaded dynamically and the `m_close` might be added to the `message` element using `showMessage()` method.

so try

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    showMessage();
    $( '#message' ).slideDown( 'fast' );

    //Hide Message//
    $( '#message' ).on('click', '#m_close', function( event ) {
        $( '#message' ).slideUp( 'fast' );
    });
    //---//
    $( '#m_button' ).click(function( event ) {
        showMessage();
        $( '#message' ).slideDown( 'fast' );
    });
});
```

when you use `click` to register a click event handler, it register the handler to only those elements that exists in the dom at that moment. when you call `showMessage` again teh existing `m_close` is removed and a new one is created so the `click` handler is no more attached to the new element. The solution here is to use event delegation as shown above

Comment: Yeah that worked, but why? what does dynamic generation have to do with it? It is generated (dynamically) once in the document ready, so why does it not work when it is generated in a click event?